# Asterisk + SIP Phone

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Пытаюсь прицепить Panasonic KX-TGP500 к Asterisk 11.2 + FreePBX 12.

В настройках базы телефона (через web-интерфейс) пишу IP сервера, ID, пароль.
В FreePBX добавляю Generic SIP device, задаю номер, имя, пароль, порты и IP базы.

При попытке из вне позвонить на телефон вылазит:
**WARNING[6582][C-00000001]: app_dial.c:2330 dial_exec_full: Dial argument takes format (technology/resource)**

Экстеншн в конфиге прописан
exten => +1234567890,1,Answer()
exten => +1234567890,n,Dial(SIP,100)  ;SayDigits(123456789)
exten => +1234567890,n,Hangup()

Если убрать Dial и отсавить SayDigits то при звонке подымет трубку и проговорит цифры.

Настраивал вот по этому материалу, кроме создания SIP транка, так как звоню на сервер астериска по мобильному через GPRS шлюз.

[Настройка Asterisk 1.8 + FreePBX 2.10 с нуля](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154933/)

Так же если кто знает объясните принцип работы sip-телефона, ему обязательно надо в интернет к sip-провайдеру или же он может в автономную работу в пределах офиса цепляясь к астериску? Астериск при этом выходит в мир через gprs-шлюз.

Comment: Приложите лог звонка на проблемный exten.

Comment: Появился более масштабный вопрос, оформлю отдельно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WARNING говорит вам, что в функцию Dial пересылаются неверные данные. Правильный формат в вашем exten должен быть такой:

```
exten => +1234567890,1,Answer()
 same => n,Dial(SIP/100) 
 same => n,SayDigits(123456789) ; Это выполнится в случае если SIP/100 занят/недоступен
 same => n,Hangup()
```

> Так же если кто знает объясните принцип работы sip-телефона, ему обязательно надо в интернет к sip-провайдеру или же он может в автономную работу в пределах офиса цепляясь к астериску?

Может и напрямую подцепляться к оператору, может и только к астериск а через него уже в мир. Как настроите. Есть телефоны которые поддерживают несколько сип аккаунтов одновременно.

Comment: Помогло, но к сожалению вылазит иная ошибка, что самое интересное с софтофоном такая схема работает, звонки идут на другую машину с Zoiper'ом, а на телефон не проходят.